# Schiller quotation concerning eternity

Tags: quotes

Erich von Manstein (Verlorene Siege) quoted Schiller as having said:

> What we omit from a single hour is lost to all eternity.

I have found similar things in Schiller’s writings, but not this exact sentence. Is it a true quotation?

Comment: *I have found similar things in Schiller's writings, but not this exact sentence.* – IIRC, Schiller wrote in German. So, I suppose you want the closest translation? If yes, you should elaborate what dissatisfying findings you have, otherwise you might get those as an answer.

Comment: Also, you may want to take a look at [this Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature?referrer=x5gk8vOgaR9D4yRnMOivZg2).

Answer (score 3):

I have found it:

> Was man von der Minute ausgeschlagen
>   Gibt keine Ewigkeit zurück

Schiller, Gedichte, Stanza 18